# The second type of conditional clause (the type contradictory to a current fact)

Tags: conditionals, clauses, subordinate-clauses

I have a question in regard to the second type of conditional (the type contradictory to a current fact). I know that the clause should be in past tense, but if there's an adjective clause, should it be in past tense too, as a consequence of the conditional clause?

If u had a chance to choose whether Trump (keeps/kept) leading the country or Obama (replaces/replaced) him, which one would u choose?

Comment: It's **you**, not **u**. And the subjunctive often uses *were* (which is past tense), so I don't necessarily agree with your *should be in past tense* statement. Your example sentence (both the first verb and the second) can actually use any number of tenses, all without a problem. (Note that *types of conditionals* is poor grammar categorization used by ESL—not native-English—courses that is imprecise and often misleading.)

Comment: What is the term natives use instead of "types of conditionals"? And let me get it straight. So, it is okay to use the present or the past for the example as long as those two verbs are consistent, right?

Comment: [Here](http://www2.gol.com/users/norris/articles/conditionals.html) and [here](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf) (PDF) are a couple of articles on the problem with the traditional method in which conditionals are taught. In brief, they are somewhat too simplistic to describe all actual uses—the way some sentences are constructed don't fit into any of the classifications.

Comment: *If you **had** a chance to choose whether Trump **will keep** leading the country or Obama **replaces** him, which one would you choose?* The mix of the tenses here isn't completely natural, but it's also not actually wrong.